# Reverse Http Proxy Server masking 3Tiers architecture into 2Tiers

Tags: windows, http, architecture, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a platform archicture with 3 Tiers (Presentation Tier, Application Tier and Data Tier).

I'm currently building a Web Api on the Presentation Tier with OData. I have read that microsoft is going to deprecate OData with WFC, since they don't have enough recourses to continue the project. As an alternative, I want to mascarade the 3Ties platform into 2Tiers, so that OData (on the Presentation Tier) could have direct access to Data Tier.

In order to achieve this I need a Reverse Http Proxy Server right?

Which reliable opensource/free Reverse Http Proxy Servers exists for windows?

Answer (score 0):

Apache has a great reverse proxy built in (using mod_proxy).  I've used it for years.

http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC11/configure-apache-httpd-as-a-reverse-proxy-modproxy.html
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html